# localhost refused to connect after running Django server

Tags: network, python, proxy

I have looked at the questions similar to this and found none that matches. I was running PCcharm and Python and had to start the Django server. The first time I ran it worked fine but when I edited some of the files to change the website that Django created, I can no longer get to localhost to see the website that I created.

I have tried rebooting, rebooted router and lastly under network preferences and proxies, I added in the localhost address, 127.0.0.1

Anyone, please help as I cannot continue with my Python class without localhost as that's where the wesite I am creating is displayed!

Comment: What port are you setting for the Django app?

Comment: Hi it's using port 8000

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what "rnter" means ! Do you mean router?

Comment: What is the exact URL that you enter